# RequireJS - config; paths and shims not working

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a `common.js` that defines the config for RequireJS:

```
(function(requirejs) {
    "use strict";

    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: "/js",
        paths: {
            "jsRoutes": "http://localhost:8080/app/jsroutes"
        },
        shim: {
            "jsRoutes": {
                exports: "jsRoutes"
            }
        }
    });

    requirejs.onError = function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    };
})(requirejs);
```

I then have a `main.js` file that I try to use the `jsRoutes` path that I created:

```
require(["./common", "jsRoutes"], function (common, routes) {
    // do something interesting
});
```

but I do not load the resource at `http://localhost:8080/app/jsroutes` instead it tries to load `http://localhost:8080/js/jsRoutes.js` when the `main.js` is executed. But this resouce doesn't exist and I get a 404.

How do I get the `jsRoutes` path to work correctly? Also do I need the shim (I'm not 100% sure)?

I can debug into the `common.js` file, so the paths should be being set, right?

**Update 1**

I believe that the paths should work as I have them defined shouldn't they?

Excerpt from http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

> There may be times when you do want to reference a script directly and not conform to the "baseUrl + paths" rules for finding it. If a module ID has one of the following characteristics, the ID will not be passed through the "baseUrl + paths" configuration, and just be treated like a regular URL that is relative to the document:

```
Ends in ".js".
Starts with a "/".
Contains an URL protocol, like "http:" or "https:".
```

**Update 2**

I may have misread the docs, I can solve the issue by defining the `main.js` like so:

```
require(["./common", "http://localhost:8080/app/jsroutes"], function (common, routes) {
    // do something interesting
});
```

I was rather hoping not to have to pass round this rather unwieldy URL though.

**Update 3**

Further investigation of the docs revealed the following snippet:

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min'
    }
});


//Later
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    //Do something with $ here
}, function (err) {
    //The errback, error callback
    //The error has a list of modules that failed
    var failedId = err.requireModules && err.requireModules[0];
    if (failedId === 'jquery') {
        //undef is function only on the global requirejs object.
        //Use it to clear internal knowledge of jQuery. Any modules
        //that were dependent on jQuery and in the middle of loading
        //will not be loaded yet, they will wait until a valid jQuery
        //does load.
        requirejs.undef(failedId);

        //Set the path to jQuery to local path
        requirejs.config({
            paths: {
                jquery: 'local/jquery'
            }
        });

        //Try again. Note that the above require callback
        //with the "Do something with $ here" comment will
          //be called if this new attempt to load jQuery succeeds.
        require(['jquery'], function () {});
    } else {
        //Some other error. Maybe show message to the user.
    }
});
```

It would seem here that the `jquery` path is working with a full URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I realised what I was doing wrong. It was simple really.

I had dependencies for `./common` and `jsRoutes` being passed to the same module so `jsRoutes` was being required before it had been defined by the config.

I moved the dependency from the `main.js` file to where it was actually needed and things worked as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain your path should be relative to your baseUrl. So giving it the domain & port is screwing it up.

EDIT: My standard require js config... it might help?

```
require.config({
  baseUrl : "./",
    paths: {

    // Bower Components
    respond:      'assets/bower_components/respond/dest/respond.min',

    // Libraries & Polyfills
    polyfillGCS:  'assets/js/lib/polyfill-getComputedStyle', 
    polyfillRAF:  'assets/js/lib/polyfill-requestAnimationFrame',
    polyfillPro:  'assets/js/lib/polyfill-promise', 
    easing:       'assets/js/lib/easing',
    signalsui:    'assets/js/lib/Signals.ui',
    signalsjs:    'assets/js/lib/Signals',
    domReady:     'assets/js/lib/domReady', // TODO: Still needed?

    // Modules
    app:          'assets/js/es5/app'

    },
    shim: {
    app: {
      deps: ['signalsjs']
    },
    signalsjs: {
      deps: ['easing', 'polyfillGCS', 'polyfillRAF']
    },
    signalsui: {
      deps: ['signalsjs']
    }
    }
});

// Load the app
require(['app']);
```

Comment: I thought I could do this, see my update 1. Am I wrong?

Comment: Please refer to the bottom code pane on the page http://www.webjars.org/documentation  it would seem they are doing something similar to what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please see my update 3, an example from the docs using a full URL

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I fixed it by changing my code like your original code:

```js
require(["./common", "jsRoutes"], function (common, routes) {
    // do something interesting
});
```

to this:

```js
require(["./common"], function (common) {
    require(["jsRoutes"], function (routes) {
        // do something interesting
    });
});
```

I'm guessing that, in the original code, RequireJS attempts to load the `"jsRoutes"` dependency *before* the configuration changes made in `"common"` are applied. Nesting the `require` calls effectively ensures that the second dependency is loaded only after the first is evaluated.